# Is there a file size limit for pictures deployed as html sites on heroku?

Tags: heroku, jpeg

I'm having issues getting a .JPG picture file to display on Heroku app site. The picture loads locally when I open the html file in my browser locally but I get 404 unable to find image when I push it to heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `404` error means not found, this does not correspond to file size so does not suggest there is a limit, check you have the correct path to the image.